# Расположение трех блоков внутри блока с заданной высотой

Tags: css3, css, html, html5

Есть блок main с **ЗАДАННОЙ** высотой в пикселях.
Есть 3 внутренних блока:

- **top** - должен масштабироваться по контенту и ужимать блок **middle**
- **middle** - должен быть с появляющейся полосой прокрутки (если
     не хватает места контенту)
- **buttom** - с фиксированной высотой в пикселях

Как сделать так, чтобы блок main **НЕ растягивался**, а оставался такой же высотой, в тоже время **блок top ужимал блок middle своим содержимым**?

```
#main{
    height:200px !important;
    width:100px;
    background:blue;
}
#top{
    background:green;
}
#middle{
    background:red;
    height:100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#buttom{
    background:blue;
    height:50px;
    bottom:0
}

<div id="main">
    <div id="top">Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</div>
    <div id="middle">Текст текст текст Текст текст текст Текст текст текст Текст текст текст Текст текст текст Текст текст текст Текст текст текст Текст текст текст </div>
    <div id="buttom">Текст текст текст</div>
</div>
```

Есть какие-нибудь предположения, как так сделать?
http://jsfiddle.net/5fCcy/3/

Comment: Сразу замечу: height 100% - элемент примет высоту родителя. А если у родителя 200px то далее думаю понятно.

Второе, что непонятно, до каких пределов можно уменьшать блок middle?

Comment: пока полностью не захлопнется.
Ну либо какой-то минимум, любой.

По поводу height, да, я прекрасно понимаю, что высота родителя.
Просто сделал для наглядности проблемы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У CSS с высотой вообще большие проблемы, так что я бы не мучился и решил [через JS](http://jsfiddle.net/6mfKG/). Скрипт можно упростить, это я для наглядности так расписал. А пользователи с отключенным JS пусть смотрят упрощенную версию сайта :)

Comment: Спасибо, пользователи с отключенным js меня не интересуют =)
Все равно, пока что жду, может кто на css подскажет как сделать. 
Интересно для себя уже.